# What is literary reputation?

Tags: meaning

I came across the sentence.." Historians exhumed the literary reputation of novelist Jack London" Could anyone explain what literary reputation means? I get the idea, but want to know the definition of it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked dictionary definitions of “literary” and “reputation”?

Comment: Yes, I have. I thought it could mean something else; maybe I was thinking too much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack London's "literary reputation" is: what literary scholars think of his writing.  Saying that it was "exhumed" (look it up) means that, up to that time, his literary reputation had been "dead", but afterward was "living".

Comment: Thank you, GEdgar!